# What does a bounded struct `where MyStruct<V>: Debug` achieve?

Tags: rust

Why would you do

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Inner<V> {
    value: V,
}

struct MyStructA<V>
where
    Inner<V>: Debug,
    V: Debug,
{
    value: V,
}
```

instead of just

```
struct MyStructB<V>
where
    V: Debug,
{
    value: V,
}
```

I'm specifically interested in what value `where Inner<V>: Debug` adds instead of `where V: Debug`. Would there ever be a reason that the complier cares more about this or is it just for human documentation? Unless I am mistaken, it does not appear that the `where Inner<V>: Debug` adds any extra bounds.

```
fn main() {
    let my_struct_a = MyStructA {
        value: Inner { value: 23 },
    };

    let my_struct_a_with_inner = MyStructA { value: 49 };

    let my_struct_b = MyStructB { value: 64 };

    let my_struct_b_with_inner = MyStructB {
        value: Inner { value: 23 },
    };
}
```

[Playground with the code.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=479a2b77a3a98436b929b1bc31aeb2f3)

Comment: *Does* anyone actually write that?

Comment: They probably do because they can even though it seems to add no perceived value. I wanted to know if there is value that I am not perceiving. There is even another way to write it as `where Inner<V>: Debug` works as opposed to `where Inner<V>: Debug, V: Debug` or `where V: Debug`.

Comment: In this case `T<U>` should be debug, assuming `U` is actually debug. I don't often see code like this.

Comment: @Dan Who exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not add any bounds. It says that `Inner<V>` implements `Debug` - which happens when `V` implements `Debug`, so it is the same as the second bound. It is probably done for documentation.